# Ubuntu 20.04 Touchscreen on Lenovo Yoga

Tags: touchscreen

Touchscreen not working on Lenovo Yoga Laptop running 20.04 LTS released today.

Looking forward to a solution to this issue.

Comment: It works after boooting the laptop. But if I close the laptop, and login again, then the touching the screen does not move the cursor anymore.

Comment: @guettli - Please see [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365498/226614). I suggest you post your info in the OP.

Comment: I use a Thinkpad p15v2 with Ubuntu 21.10, and now the touchscreen works. Even after closing the laptop.

Comment: Did everything else on the Yoga work, other than the touch feature?

Comment: Good news: It works with Ubuntu 22.04 (at least on my Lenovo Laptop (P15vGen2))

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue so a few search.

I went to

https://linuxwacom.github.io/

and chose the kernel driver which led to

https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source

and basically followed the instructions and did a reboot, touch input started to work again.

For my pen input, it was working without any fix required.

Comment: Is there a simpler solution (without compiling the kernel)?

Comment: It doesn't say to recompile the kernel, it says to compile a kernel module.

Comment: What is the best way to make it work by default?

Comment: I am a user, not a kernel hacker. Above solution does not fit to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a half-comment, but it wouldn't fit or be as readable as convenient if posted as such.

### Possible causes

There are a several possible causes for the failure.
I am listing here a few, while waiting for your further info (see below).

1. Power management issues. Drivers often have options for this.
2. Newer kernel required. This is easily solved by updating the system, `$ sudo apt update` - `$ sudo apt upgrade` - reboot.

### Further info

Please post:

1. The output of a few commands below (you might need to install `neofetch`).

   ```
   $ uname -a
   $ neofetch
   ```
2. The complete model (e.g., Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 15IMH05)
3. The output, when the touchscreen is working (*WKC*) and when it is not (*NKW*), of (you may need to install `libinput-tools`)

   ```
   $ xinput
   $ ubuntu-drivers devices
   $ sudo lspci -vnn
   $ hwinfo
   $ lsmod
   $ sudo libinput list-devices
   ```

   Note 1: the output of `hwinfo` and `lsmod` is long. You could use pastebin.

   Note 2: `sudo` is important in front of `lspci`, as it lists devices capabilities, including power management, see above.
4. Any information that helps identifying: 1) the drivers used by the touchscreen, by comparing *WKC* and *NKW*, 2) hardware, 3) problems (`dmesg`, `journalctl`, etc.)
5. Did you try the suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1234852/226614)?

### Related

1. [Touchpad not working on Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 15IMH05](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283455/touchpad-not-working-on-lenovo-yoga-slim-7-15imh05)
2. https://askubuntu.com/a/1358477/226614
3. https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/Ideapad-5-15ARE05-Touchscreen-not-working/m-p/5017099

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the latest kernel (>5.10.4) detects the touchscreen (Wacom digitizer) no problem. No need to compile, just add the kernel ppa and upgrade the kernel from the package manager.

```
sudo apt-add-repository -U https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
sudo apt update
sudo apt install <your kernel package here>
# or if you don't mind upgrading everything upgradable
sudo apt upgrade
```

[Touchpad not working on Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 15IMH05](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283455/touchpad-not-working-on-lenovo-yoga-slim-7-15imh05/1304150?noredirect=1#comment2236022_1304150)

Comment: apt-add-repository does not have -U option.

Comment: Did everything else on the Yoga work too? Sound, Screen brightness/contrast, Hibernation ... and other driver prone stuff?

Comment: Currently up to date OS, sound, screen brightness working. All known drivers working. I don't believe hibernation is working but sleep does, drains battery pretty fast while sleeping though (almost out of battery even after just a day of sleep)