# Touchpad not working on Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 15IMH05

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I recently purchased a Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 and installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10. Everything works perfectly on Windows but the touchpad does not work on Linux. Also it makes weird sounds from time to time.

I cannot see the touchpad when I do the `xinput` command.

What can I do ?

Comment: Did the posted answer actually help you in the end? If so, please mark it as the accepted answer, so as to give feedback for others who may have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the latest (or a newer) kernel from [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) (5.10.4 today).

Comment: has this specifically worked for you?

Comment: Not sure what fixed it in the end, but I think it's this.

Comment: Hello, sorry but I have returned the computer so I am not able to test the answer...