# Touchpad not working when booting live USB of 19.04 or 20.04

Tags: boot, 20.04, touchpad, live-usb, input

I am using a Lenovo Yoga laptop that came with Windows. I then did a dual boot with Fedora, then realized that I want to switch to/add Ubuntu.

I've tried booting Ubuntu 19.04 and 20.04 as live USB, and both times my touchpad hardly worked. With 20, I could get it to move very slowly and irregularly, but with 19 it didn't move at all. It actually wasn't even detecting it as an input source.

If I install, will this problem persist? I hope it's just a live USB problem.  But if it's not, does anyone know what the cause/solution could be? I used balenaEtcher for the iso and it said successful.

Comment: If it doesn’t work in the LiveCD, it almost definitely won’t work when installed. That said, there are ways to make it work, like in this question https://askubuntu.com/q/1283455/1438484

Comment: 19.04 is out of the question, it's out of support, it shouldn't be used and there's no reason to, period. You can try 21.04, maybe it has better support.

Comment: Please be specific; Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is a LTS release so has different kernel options available (GA or HWE); so did you try the 5.4? (20.04 & 20.04.1 desktop) 5.8? (20.04.2) or 5.11? (20.04.3?) for desktop, or are you asking about server? (GA or 5.4 unless you change it during *live* session for install).  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has many options - you didn't specify a product (server? desktop) let alone what software stack was included on that ISO (ie. point release).

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades