# Touchscreen not working on Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, touchscreen

touchscreen on my Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5 is not working and neither is the pen. I tried following this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1234852/928890 but it didn't work. Are there any other options regarding this problem?

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

Output of `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 06cb:00be Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 5986:212a Acer, Inc Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `xinput` command:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 06CB:CE2D Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 06CB:CE2D Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just bought also an IdeaPad Flex 5 14", and have the exact same issue. I sucessfully compiled and loaded wacom and wacom_w8001 modules, but it didn't help.

Note that on my system - like yours but unlike some other posts, there has never been any elan* driver loaded.

```
$ dmesg | grep MSFT
[    0.607606] i2c_hid i2c-MSFT0001:00: i2c-MSFT0001:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.607617] i2c_hid i2c-MSFT0001:00: i2c-MSFT0001:00 supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.772231] input: MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-MSFT0001:00/0018:04F3:3140.0001/input/input5
[    0.772281] input: MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-MSFT0001:00/0018:04F3:3140.0001/input/input6
[    0.772317] hid-generic 0018:04F3:3140.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140] on i2c-MSFT0001:00
[    2.261795] input: MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-MSFT0001:00/0018:04F3:3140.0001/input/input8
[    2.265094] input: MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-MSFT0001:00/0018:04F3:3140.0001/input/input9
[    2.279085] hid-multitouch 0018:04F3:3140.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140] on i2c-MSFT0001:00
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 06cb:00be Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174f:243f Syntek Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ uname -r
5.4.0-59-generic
```

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Also, output in Xorg log :

```
    89.235] (==) modeset(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    89.381] (II) config/udev: Adding input device MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse1)
[    89.382] (II) config/udev: Adding input device MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse (/dev/input/event6)
[    89.382] (**) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    89.382] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse'
[    89.429] (**) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse: always reports core events
[    89.430] (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse Pointingstick
[    89.431] (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse: device is a pointer
[    89.431] (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse: device removed
[    89.431] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 12)
[    89.432] (**) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    89.432] (**) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    89.432] (**) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    89.433] (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse Pointingstick
[    89.433] (II) event6  - MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse: device is a pointer
[    89.434] (II) config/udev: Adding input device MSFT0001:00 04F3:3140 Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
```

Like others, touchscreen works perfectly on Windows 10 (dual boot). I would say we don't have a good working driver available - yet ?

Alex

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven't worked it out yet as well. I kinda gave up and I just accepted that I can't have a touchscreen for now. It's a shame because it's a really cool feature in the laptop.

Comment: So bad indeed :(

Comment: Actually it has been solved, and merged into kernel 5.10.4 (at least 5.11.0-rc2) https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/issues/218
didn't try it yet but many report as fixed !

Comment: Just updated kernel to 5.10.4 and happily saying my touchscreen is working now :))

Comment: I'll try it out now. Thanks a lot man! Cheers!